# Moderated Mediation: MANOVA and PROCESS different results

Tags: manova, mediation, interaction

I have to calculate a moderated mediation with 2 mediators and 2 dependent variables.

**My model:**

- predictor (dichotomous)
- moderator (dichotomous)
- both mediators (continous)
- both dependent variables (continous)

My professor told my first to check my model with a MANOVA. After that I calculated my moderated mediation model with PROCESS (Hayes).

My problem is that I get different main effect results! Interaction significance are in MANOVA and PROCESS the same.

For example:

- MANOVA: predictor is significant, moderator not
- PROCESS: predictor is not significant, moderator is significant

But If I mean center in PROCESS my model I got similar results. But many people say to me that mean centering both dichotomous variable because it doesnt make any sense.

What is the problem?